# Getting templates images on Mosaico

Tags: mosaico

in Mosaico templates the images the images can't be seen.
I don't understand why they are uploaded through this link:

```
GET https://mydomain.com/mosaico/img/?method=placeholder&params=534,200

[HTTP/1.1 401 not found]
```

I think normally it should be `https://mydomain.com/civicrm/mosaico/img/?method=placeholder&params=534,200`, but both these url give me "401 not found" and CIVICRM_CLEANURL is enabled.

This is my configuration:

CiviCRM Version: 5.28.0 on Wordpress
Mosaico 2.4.1592820024
Wordpress: 5.5

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is actually to do with the base page url - it should **not** have a trailing slash. @massetto knows this I think, because he created the [GitHub issue where this is explained](https://github.com/veda-consulting-company/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/issues/398) so this answer is really for anyone else looking at this later.

From Matt Wire of Veda:

> Check your CiviCRM paths/resource URLs and make sure that you are not overriding them if you don't need to.
>
> In CiviCRM make sure that "Wordpress Base Page" is setup as "civicrm" with no "/" - see civicrm/civicrm-core#18332 so this will be fixed in 5.29.
>
> In Wordpress make sure you have a CiviCRM base page (should be at https://yoursite.com/civicrm).
> Important: Go to Settings -> Permalinks and click "Save Changes".
>
> Now Mosaico images should work and navigating to https://yoursite.com/civicrm/mosaico/img should give a 200 OK and a blank page.

v5.29 is available now, so sounds like upgrading to that should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a permissions error in your `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext` directory. You can probably resolve this by assigning ownership to `www-data`.

e.g. if your site is installed at `/var/www/html` then you can fix this with:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm
```

I've often thought it would be easier if Mosaico stored images in the WordPress image library but presumably this isn't possible with a multi-CMS extension.

Comment: It doesn't depend on permission.  
Unfortunately I had not read this [Important Notice](https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice) and the installed version of Wordpress was 5.4.  
Now I have updated wordpress to 5.5 and the image has this _src_: `https://mydomain.com/mosaico/img/?method=placeholder&params=534,200`.  
I think normally it should be `https://mydomain.com/civicrm/mosaico/img/?method=placeholder&params=534,200`,but both these url give me "401 not found" and `CIVICRM_CLEANURL` is enabled.

Comment: Huh, you're totally right. Now I have the same problem...