# Problem with path to Mosaico versafix template

Tags: drupal, mosaico

After Drupal (9.5.3) and CiviCRM (5.58.1) updates last week, all versafix-based templates are just displaying a blank screen. I had also updated Mosaico to the latest, but reverting to the version in use last week hasn't helped.

The problem is that something is adding /en/ to the template path, but the files are in the folder without a language id.

The Drupal site is multilingual (to allow for webforms in different languages) but CiviCRM is not.

(GET https://secure.srigeneva.org/**en**/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/template-versafix-1.html 404).

The file is where it says it should be, permissions 644.

https://secure.srigeneva.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/templates/versafix-1/template-versafix-1.html

I can create new versafix templates, but not use them.

What works for today is to copy messages that worked last week and replace the contents, but several templates were created last week and not used so we can't pull them up.

Does anyone know how that /en is getting put into the path to the template?

Kathryn

Answer (score 2):

Nothing else I could find worked so I totally removed and reinstalled Mosaico and can now use Versafix-1 to create and use new templates.

Answer (score 0):

Check you extension url in Resource URL settings(CiviCRM >> System Settings >> Resource url)

Comment: It's set to [civicrm.files]/ext/. [civicrm_files] is correctly as https://secure.srigeneva.org/sites/default/files/civicrm

Comment: Now that I'm looking for it, all of my CiviCRM pages are showing up with /en/ (I can take it out and they still appear, but clicking on any link goes to /en/civicrm/...

Comment: I found another question that seems to have a similar problem so I'll try that solution. https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/38177/3596

Comment: That didn't work, so I went back and removed and reinstalled Mosaico and it's working now (all of our recent new templates are still grey screen but we can make new ones. Hopefully this doesn't happen often because we've made a lot of templates to do system messages so it's a lot of wasted work every time.

Comment: The new templates had the same issue shortly after posting above. I went back to Mosaico 2.9 and it's working again.

Comment: Same here in civi 5.61.3

I replicate a production site on a sandbox domain. I then use the extension "Mosaico Extension Directory Changes" to update all the Mosaico paths from production URL to sandbox URL. 

I then go to Mailings->Mosaico Templates and I see the list of all my custom templates. In Mosaico 2.9 I can view all my templates, edit them, etc (and same with draft mailings).

I then update to Mosaico 2.12 and when I return to edit templates/draft newsletters, editor page opens with just a gray background and nothing else.

Only solution is to not update to 2.12